# Having the deque with the advantages of Queue in a thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue, deque

I need a structure where I will be able to pop() and append() to the right side (just like deque), while having the structure blocking and waiting if it is empty (just like Queue). I could directly use a Queue, but I need also the nice feature of deque where items are removed without blocking if the structure is full.

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(maxlen=2)
d.append(1)
d.append(2)
d.append(3) # d should be [2,3] (it is the case)
d.pop()
d.pop()
d.pop() # should wait (not the case)
```

Is it better to subclass deque (making it wait) or Queue (adding a popLeft function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating your own queue mixing the best of both?

```
import queue as Queue
from collections import deque

class QueuePro:
  def __init__(self, maxlenDeque): 
    self.deque = deque(maxlen=maxlenDeque)
    self.queue = Queue.Queue()

  def append(self, elem):
    self.deque.append(elem)
    self.queue.put(elem)

  def pop(self):
    if(not self.deque):
      self.queue.get()
    else:
      self.deque.pop()
      self.queue.get()


q2 = QueuePro(2)
q2.append(1)
q2.append(2)

q2.pop()
q2.pop()
q2.pop()
#waiting
```

Comment: Both solutions are good but I feel this one more elegant, thank you!

Comment: Once queue size increases beyond deque size it won't have an opportunity to reduce it to deque size ever again. Meaning you will keep 'dequed' objects in the queue while the object is alive.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure which is better, but here's an idea for adding *wait on pop* with `threading.Event`

```
from collections import deque
from threading import Event

class MyDeque(deque):
    def __init__(self, max_length):
        super().__init__(maxlen=max_length)
        self.not_empty = Event()
        self.not_empty.set()

    def append(self, elem):
        super().append(elem)
        self.not_empty.set()

    def pop(self):
        self.not_empty.wait()  # Wait until not empty, or next append call
        if not (len(q) - 1):
            self.not_empty.clear()
        return super().pop()

q = MyDeque(2)
q.append(1)
q.append(2)
q.append(3)
q.pop()
q.pop()
q.pop()  # Waits
```

Comment: A small error:  should be `if not (len(self) -1):`  Also, in this formulation, deque.append() and .pop() work as a LIFO.  The equivalent in Queue.put() and .get() actions are FIFO

Comment: I think that the self.not_empty.set() should be removed. Moreover, I think that this implementation is not safe if more threads can remove objects from the queue. The pop function should be locked in order to guarantee that only one thread at a time can remove objects from the queue. I provide the suggested modifications in a new answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution provided by Cisco, I provide this solution to solve two problems: 1) remove the set() operation in the constructor, which caused errors if a pop was performed after the queue was created. 2) Make the queue safe in the case of multiple threads reading from the queue.

```py
from collections import deque
from threading import Event
from threading import Lock

class BlockingDeque(deque):
    def __init__(self, max_length):
        super().__init__(maxlen=max_length)
        self.not_empty = Event()
        self.popLock = Lock()
        self.appendLock = Lock()

    def append(self, elem):
        with self.appendLock:
            super().append(elem)
            self.not_empty.set()
        

    def popleft(self):
        with self.popLock:
            self.not_empty.wait()
            with self.appendLock:
                if not (len(self) - 1):
                    self.not_empty.clear()
                toReturn = super().popleft()
        return toReturn
```

Comment: I tried that one, it is working too, thanks!